# why sbt about giving error while executing sbt about command

Tags: scala, sbt

I followed the steps to install :

```
wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-0.13.16.rpm
```

And install by yum

```
sudo yum install sbt-0.13.16.rpm
```

Check it with sbt about

```
sbt about
```

It give me an error please help with this issue

```
$ sbt about
[info] Loading project definition from /../scala/2.11.12/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from //scala/2.11.12/project
[info] Updating {file://scala/2.11.12/project/}root-2-11-12-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving key references (10396 settings) ...
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /scratch)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /scratch)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /scratch)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
        at VersionUtil$$anonfun$versionPropertiesImpl$1.apply(VersionUtil.scala:81)
        at VersionUtil$$anonfun$versionPropertiesImpl$1.apply(VersionUtil.scala:61)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: What Java version are you using? Could you try it with Java 8?

Comment: I am using java 8

`$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)`

Comment: It seems your project uses some  kind of plugin which calls out to `git` to determine the current branch / commit or whatever. Since you are not in a git repository, this fails. Do as it said: "use `last` for the full log." This might give you a clue where it failed exactly.